# Android: `Could not find element /manifest/application` issue

Tags: android

After a long search onine I came out empty.

Inside `ComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices4323.aar` under `build->exploded-bundle` I have a `AndroidMenifest.xml` file without `<application/>` tag.

When I'm adding the tag, it's automatically removed when trying to build or synch the project and Android Studio says that I cannot edit `.aar` files

So, on one hand I'm missing the tag, on the other hand I cannot add it.

The error I get is:

```
 :gps:processDebugManifest[C:\Apps\social\gps\build\exploded-bundles\ComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices4323.aar\AndroidManifest.xml:1] Could not find element /manifest/application.
```

repeatedly.

I have in my build grade file-

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
```

I tried-

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.+'
```

and

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

not working.
This problem appeared after I updated and install new packages from sdk manager.

Any idea?

Comment: what are you trying to do with google play services exactly? use the user guide i added below to use google play services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
```

as per http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html